# mssql trigger - selecting specific data from the INSERTED table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I got an Audit table to track the insert / update operations.
My problem is that on update there are 2 cases.
1) regular update 
2) update to a field called Isdeleted from false to true.

I tried to separate both of the cases but i am missing something, i am new to triggers.

```
DECLARE @Action AS CHAR(1)
DECLARE @Count AS INT


SET @Action = 'I' 
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM DELETED
if @Count > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Action = 'D' 
        SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED WHERE INSERTED.IsDeleted = 0
        IF @Count > 0
            SET @Action = 'U' 
    END
```

What i want to do is to get to Action = 'D'  when the only value that was changed was IsDeleted ( from false to true ).
And 'U' when any of the other values were changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you created your trigger, you can modify it to make use of `UPDATE()` to simplify the logic of setting the value of `@Action`.

For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON myTable AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Action AS CHAR(1)

    IF UPDATE(isDeleted)
        SET @Action = 'U'

END
```

This will fire everytime but only `SET` the value of `@Action` when there is a change on the `isDeleted` column, which I think is what you're looking for.

I'm not sure what you're going to do with this onward, but it will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This select will return the number of rows that the IsDeleted column was updated from 0 to 1:

```
select count(*) 
from inserted inner join deleted on <fk_column(s)> 
where deleted.IsDeleted = 0 
and inserted.IsDeleted = 1
```

However, since triggers works per statement (and not per row), there could be cases where some rows are deleted and some are just updated, so keeping the action per row might be a little more tricky then that.

Answer (score 0):

try This :

---

```
DECLARE @Action AS CHAR(1)
DECLARE @Count AS INT

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Deleted)
BEGIN
   SELECT
      @Action = 'I'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN

   SELECT
     @Count = COUNT(1)
    FROM Inserted Ins
      INNER JOIN Deleted Del 
        ON Ins.SeqNo = Del.SeqNo
        WHERE ISNULL(Ins.IsDeleted,0) <> ISNULL(Del.IsDeleted,0)
            AND Ins.Column1 = Del.Column1
            AND Ins.Column2 = Del.Column2
            AND Ins.ColumnN = Del.ColumnN

   SELECT
    @Action = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Count,0)>0
                THEN 'D'
                ELSE 'U' END

END

SELECT
  [ActionCode] = @Action
```